# Is there a native type to refer to JSON data types?

Tags: json, typescript

Instead of doing:

```
let foo: string | number | boolean ... = ...
```

Is there any TypeScript keyword to refer to all [JSON data types](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp)?

This is what I expect:

```
let foo: JsonDataType = ...
```

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1897

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe but that is not what I am asking.

Comment: In what way is your question different?

Comment: I am asking if there is keyword for JSON data types. I am not asking for a JSON type. No is a valid answer.

Comment: OK, what is a "keyword"? How is it different to a type, in that case? I am really not sure what you're actually asking now, since you've disagreed with what aligns with my interpretation of your question.

Comment: No, there is no such keyword, nor is there a provided type (which would be much more likely to happen than TS reserving some identifier for this purpose)

Comment: The answer I was looking for is: "No, there isn't. But you can use this `export type JSONPrimitive = string | number | boolean | null;`"